# Were there religious wars between two sects in Hinduism?

Tags: india, cultural-history, social-history, anthropology, hinduism

[Shaivism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaivism) and [Vaishnavism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishnavism), are two major sects within the umbrella of [Hinduism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism), each with a different deity as their Supreme God.

This difference, is **[thought to have](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Ancient_Indian_History_Civilization_and/jEMpAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=shaiva%20kings%20vs%20vaishanava&dq=shaiva%20kings%20vs%20vaishanava&printsec=frontcover)**, in the ancient and even recent past, resulted in several differences and thus "religion - based wars" between the two sects. Resulting in vandalism and lootings of kingdoms of one sect by the other. The impact is posited to be present in the form of several vandalized structures found on across India.

**What's the historical veracity of these claims?**
I'd like to get an account of those war and how they might have impacted the development of both sects in terms of their theology and sometimes outright mind boggling stories. An example : The Story Of Prahalada-Narsimha, [Sharaba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharabha), Gandarbherunda, [Prtayangira](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyangira).

Comment: If I get some time tomorrow I might look into it, but in general I've found the development of sects usually follows cultural/ethnic lines. So if you take their avowed doctrinal differences at face value, you're usually missing the real point.

Comment: I doubt very much if you can find something useful. Wars, especially religious wars, are rarely fought for the reasons people claim.

Answer (score -2):

There is a short, simple, and clear answer to this: No. Different Sects within  Hinduism do not fight and have not fought each other based on religious differences. In fact, belief-based differences between different sects of Hinduism are very small and rare. Most differences between the sects of Hinduism are practice-based.

Hinduism is a polytheistic, decentralized religion. We have no central authority and there is no "king" of Hinduism, like how Christianity has a pope and how Islam had a Caliph. We are also encouraged to have multiple gods and deities to pray to. (There's more nuance to it: For more details see the answer to [this][1] post). Vaishnavites spend more time and dedication towards Vishnu, but the accept and revere Shiva. Shaivites spend more time and dedication towards Shiva, but they accept and revere Vishnu. Their beliefs are the same, but their priorities and practices vary a little.

A common notion amongst Hindus is that the same god can have many names. For example, [Ganesha][2] has other names such as Ganapati and Vinayaka, but also many different tribal names for him.

So, there were and are no hate or war between Shaivites and Vaishnavites.

Why didn't Hinduism schism? The reason is simple. Centralized Religions typically Schism, while decentralized religions typically never schism. For example, Islam had a schism between Sunnis and Shias, because of a dispute of the "throne", or position of Caliph, of Islam. There is a possibility to gain power through the ladder of the centralized religions, and that leads to disputes, which lead to Schisms.
Christianity had a Schism between Catholicism and Orthodox Christianity because Christianity was a highly political force during the time. Politics leads to greed for power, and that leads to disputes, which leads to a Schism.
Meanwhile, Hinduism is a highly decentralized religion. We have no leader. This leads to no possibility of using Hinduism as a way to gain power. So, there is no power conflict, which means there is no schism.
Another reason why there was no schism in Hinduism is because, in the outdated caste system, kings have less importance than saints, which means that when a king tries to defame the other sects of Hinduism, no one will listen to him since they know that the king is not the highest authority on Hinduism, the saints are. And since saints are decentralized, there was never a schism.
Hope this makes sense! Feel free to edit this to help me.
[1]: [How did Ram and Krishna become the dominant Gods in Hinduism?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/58531/how-did-ram-and-krishna-become-the-dominant-gods-in-hinduism)
[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha

Comment: I hear adherents of nearly any religion saying the same thing.

Comment: The difference is that we are a decentralized religion, meaning that there is no central authority. Kings, who spawn war and hate, have no authority to defame other sects of Hinduism, since kings (Khatriyas) have less power than Saints (Brahmins) in the outdated caste system. The reason Islam had a Schism is that there was a distinct leadership system, and there was a dispute to the "throne" of Islam. Hinduism has no such leadership system. The reason Christianity broke down into separate parts is because of separate kingdoms (Byzantine Empire vs Western Europe) fighting each other.

Comment: While there were separate kingdoms in the ancient realm of Sanathana Dharma, they couldn't defame the other side since kings had less power than Brahmins in the terrible caste system.

Comment: A very common pattern that I see in history is that, Centralized Religions Schism, while Decentralized Religions do not.

Comment: Looking back, I should probably add all these comments to my original post. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: @Proud Tamil Indian: Your comment about Christianity breaking down into separate sects because of separate kingdoms is false, in general.  There are many instances of causation going the other way, with the differences being (in part) the cause of the separate kingdoms.

Comment: @jamesqf While the leaders of Christianity at the time may have found excuses for the Schism, the main reason for the Schism occurring is political. Rome excommunicated Michael Cerularius, which was the breaking point of the Great Schism. It was because of a centralized authority, eg. the Pope, who was fighting another centralized authority, eg. the Patriarch, which led to the Schism.

Comment: The pope and other figures in Rome did not like the fact that the Byzantine Patriarchs had power, and in retaliation, declared that the Pope had authority over the Patriarch. The pope used his power to put a lot of religious debates against the Eastern Romans as another excuse to assume power over half of Christianity.

Comment: It was a pure power grab. Divide, and hate in general, are due to the seeking of Power. A centralized ladder only ensures the seeking of power, and that ensures divide. That then ensures a schism. Just my thoughts :)

Comment: @Proud Tamil Indian: You're citing one instance, out of hundreds, possibly thousands.  And one that no longer has any real relevance in the modern world.

Comment: @jamesqf its two, not 1. I cited both the Islamic Schism and the Christian Schism. I'm trying to prove that a centralized religion leads to Schisms, so that proof doesn't necessarily need to have a relevance to the modern world. In addition, both said schisms do have a very real relevance to the modern world. The Islamic Schism is making people die as I type. Shias and Sunnis are killing each other across Iraq, Syria and other nations. Human lives are being lost. The Christian Schism has led to the fact that around 1 Billion people are Catholic and 200+ million people being Orthodox.

Comment: @jamesqf The Middle East is currently having a civil war due to the very real, relevant, Schism that was DIRECTLY MADE because of a power struggle between Ali ibn Abi Talib and his Shia followers, and Abu Bakr and his Sunni followers. If you believe that the loss of human lives is not relevant, then I cannot help you.

Comment: @Proud Tamil Indian: I thought I'd made it clear that I was only talking about Christianity, not Islam.  Nor do I agree that the current situation is about an Islamic schism.  It's more about Islamic jihadists of whatever stripe wanting to force their religion on everyone else, and those same jihadists fighting amongst themselves over the spoils & who's going to be top dog..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128617/discussion-between-proud-tamil-indian-and-jamesqf).

Comment: @Proud Tamil Indian: Let's not.  Chat does not work.  One final comment re Sunni vs Shia: as far as I understand it, the division was not about religion, it was about who was going to be in control.  Something that can be seen in any organization, from local clubs to national politics.

Comment: Exactly. Any Schism isn't about religion, it's always about who's going to be in control. And thankfully, Hinduism doesn't have someone "in control", since it is decentralized. As you say yourself, fight for power happens in any organization, and thankfully, Hinduism isn't an organization, since it's decentralized.

Comment: Do you have any more points? If not, please explain what I could do to my answer to earn your upvote. If so, please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: @jamesqf Are you interested to continue this conversation?

Comment: @Proud Tamil Indian: Not really.  But you are wrong about schisms not being caused by religious differences.  Of course they are almost always a mix of religious difference and power struggles: it just happens that the Sunni/Shia one was an extreme case of control vs religion.  Others, like Luther's break with the Catholic church, were mainly about religious doctrine.

Comment: @jamesqf I will admit that Luther's break with the Catholic Church is more religious-based rather than power-based compared with other Schisms (at least that's what the writers of history want us to think), but most of that Schism was also based on power as well. Luther believed that the Pope's power should be reduced. That was the main struggle in that Schism.

Comment: Luther was against the clergy abusing their power and selling indulgences.  He was also against some aspects of the pope's power, for example, he believes that the pope has no power over people in Purgatory

Comment: Go to the wikipedia page for the Ninety-Five Theses (which is the  founding document for Protestantism, if you didn't know). Do a search for the word "Pope" (Use Control-F or Command-F). At the time of my writing this comment, there are 28 instances of the word Pope in the document. That shows that there is a debate over power, expessially regarding the power the pope should have.

Comment: Luther wanted the pope and high Catholic leaders to lose significant amounts of power. (He didn't want it for himself, but there still was a power debate). The main reason of all Schisms is power struggles.

Comment: One of the two central beliefs of Luther was that the Bible (NOT THE POPE) is the central religious authority. See the history.com page for Martin Luther and his 95 Theses

Comment: @jamesqf Off topic, but can you help me with my other question? No one has answered and I don't know why. Also I need an answer. https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/65839/what-was-the-indian-nobilitys-reaction-to-the-construction-of-veeranam-eri-%e0%ae%b5%e0%af%80%e0%ae%b0

Comment: Please continue the debate.