# What was the Indian nobility's reaction to the construction of Veeranam Eri (வீராணம் ஏரி)?

Tags: india, battle, ancient-india

**Background Information**

In the South of Medieval India, there was a wealthy and powerful empire called the Chola Empire.

In between the years 907-955 AD, the king (or Raja) Parantaka the First (Paranthaka Cholar) was ruling the Chola Empire. Within the first 3 years of his rule, he had declared war on the rival Pandya kingdom, with Maravarman Rajasinha III at its head. One of his great accomplishments was the fact that he had captured the city of Madurai, which was a Pandyan Stronghold. [**Wikipedia Source**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parantaka_I)

[image]**(Maps Adapted from: Y. Subbarayalu, R. Gurukkal)**

After losing this vital city, the Pandyans sought to ally with the ruler of Sri Lanka (Kassapa the Fifth). The said king sent a considerable force to help the Pandyans, but the combined army was defeated by the Chola king at the battle of [Vellore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vellore). After this crushing defeat, the Pandyan royal family escaped to Sri Lanka, while Parantaka consolidated his position and took over the remaining portions of Pandya country, meaning that the Chola empire had almost all of the current territory of Tamil Nadu, with the exception of portions of parts of Northwestern TN that was controlled under the domain of the Rashtragudas, and parts of Western TN that was controlled by the weakening Chera domain at the time.

In the meantime, Parantaka married 2 Chera princesses to strengthen Chera-Chola relations. His first son was Rajaditya Cholar (with the first Chera princess) and his second son was Gandaradhitya Cholar. The third son was Arinjaya Cholar (with the second Chera princess).
(I couldn't find who Gandaradhitya Cholar's mother was, if you can find her name, then please let me know). Gandaradhitya's nature was very peaceful. He was more focused on pursuing religion than trying to acquire the throne for himself.

**[Gandaradhitya Cholar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandaraditya) [Arinjaya Cholar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arinjaya_Chola)
Source: [Video by Arunprasath Natarajan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi27nabJFoY&list=PLmIml6gO-xFT_wc67x-ycCjl-reDU6BKf&index=3)**

Near the end of Parantaka's rule, after enacting various highly successful administrative and national laws, he decided to invade Sri Lanka and kill his old rivals, Maravarman Rajasinha III and Kassapa the Fifth. He left his capable sons to administer and defend the kingdom, with Rajaditya in command, while he was on the campaign.

**Sources for the next few paragraphs: [Video by Arunprasath Natarajan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRDdVeBWw8s&list=PLmIml6gO-xFT_wc67x-ycCjl-reDU6BKf&index=4) [Article](https://www.sundaydisturbers.in/rajaditya-chola-peoples-king) [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Takkolam) [Article about the Lake itself](https://lakesofindia.com/2021/01/05/the-story-of-veeranam-lake/)**

Then, the Rashtragutans, under king Krishna the third, invaded the Chola Empire, seeing as their powerful and wise leader was gone south, and an inexperienced (but admittedly capable) son was left to defend the rich lands of the Chola Empire.

[image: Rashtraguda Empire] [**Source**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashtrakuta_dynasty#/media/File:Rashtrakuta-empire-map.svg) This is the Rashtragutan Empire around this time.

Before the Rashtragudans invaded, the Cholas were already aware that they were probably going to invade them sometime. So, the prince Rajaditya gathered his forces and requested his Chera allies to help him. They obliged, and the combined force marched to northern Tamil Nadu to watch the border.
En route, Rajaditya came across a parched land north of the Kollidam River. His army set camp near the villages in that region. (around 945-950 AD) Daily, he ordered a full third of his army to march south to the Kollidam River, gather water, and march back up with gallons of water on elephant-back to quench the thirst of his forces. Meanwhile, he also saw his thirsty citizens near that region.

After some time, he saw that some of his soldiers who were not sent to gather water were resting. This is very bad for any military general, since that means that the soldiers are becoming weaker in the face of the battle. To solve all the problems, he ordered all of his soldiers to dig a vast lake in a place of unused land. His army dug a 14-km wide pit, which has a capacity of 1.465 to 1.5 billion cubic feet of water. After the pit was completed, his army connected the Kollidam River to the pit, and watched as the pit filled with water. After this point, the people living near that region had a new water source thanks to this king. (Side note: Chennai, a current megacity with over 7 million people, uses this lake as one of its main water sources in this age as well.) He named this lake Veeranarayanapuram Lake after his father (one of his father's many names was Veeranarayanapuram), but through time, the lake is now referred to as Veeranam Lake/Veeranam Eri. (In Tamil, the language most spoken around that area, the word "Eri" is the equivalent of the English "Lake".)

The area near Veeranam Lake and Kollidam River:
[image]
**Source: Google Maps**

(The connection between the two water bodies on this map is not visible, since it is miniscule compared to the size of the Lake and the River).

This project greatly increased the popularity of Rajaditya Cholar. He became known as the "people's king", because of his popularity. This increased the morale of his troops, and message of this project spread across India.

Eventually, the battle between the Rashtragudas and the Cholas ensued. This was called the Battle of Takkolam. The Cholas lost badly, and Rajaditya was killed in the battle. This led to a period of decline within the Chola realm until 985 AD, when the legendary king Rajaraja Cholan the First took over, and brought the Chola empire to new heights. There is very little historical information about the period between 955 and 985, so I recommend looking for the reactions of people in Paranthaka's generation, since there will probably be more evidence about that than the people in Rajaditya's generation. The reason there wasn't a lot of information between 955 and 985 is due to the decline of the Chola Empire.

**Additional source: [Video based off of Wikipedia article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK-GubQ1b84)
This video is very helpful and I can't find any errors in it. Please check this one out. Skip to the year 930: [Histomap of India](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw9psR8MyPI)**

**My question:** What was reaction from Indian nobility to this project? I'm looking for an answer with the perspective of the Rashtragudan nobility, but additional information about the reactions of all Indian nobility of the time would be welcome. I want quotes from the kings and inscriptions, not simple guesses on what they would have said.

**Note about the Video Links: Some of the videos are in Tamil. I would like to apologize if you do not understand the language in which the video is in. The maker of some of these videos is Arunprasath Natarajan, who is an author and historian. These videos are published by the organization Sunday Disturbers and Publishers.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128907/discussion-on-question-by-proud-tamil-indian-what-was-the-indian-nobilitys-reac).